# Adding parameter in anchor tag in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add a username in my anchor tag's `href` property.
My Code is,

```
var Name = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <a href="www.example.com/"+ { this.props.username} +"" className="post-title">{this.props.name}</a><br />
            </div>
        );
    }

});
```

But, I am getting an error saying `undefined token +` near that href property. I think this is due to I am trying to add it in render method. So, is there any other approach?

Thank you..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the `+`. It should be:

```
<a href={"www.example.com/" + this.props.username} ...
```

Comment: I've already tried that. Then the link redirects to `http://www.example.com/{this.props.username}` instead of `http://www.example.com/anyusername`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is:

```
<a href={`https://www.example.com/${this.props.username1}`}>link</a>
```